# last index of an element in an array in java using recursion. However i have doubts shouldnt this code return the first index?

Tags: java, recursion, indexing

[the code is shown here ]

[image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTOEa.png)
Traversal of the array is from behind and if you guys can show the dry run i would be grateful.  solutions using only recursion would be grateful and i will provide the code if you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a complex formular. You can get the last index with a simple command:

```
//Suppose you have any array named arr
int lastIndex = arr.length-1; 
//you need -1 because length will start with 1, but index starts with 0.
```

At least if I understand your question correctly. If you want the first index, that will always be 0, unless if your array is null.
Does this help you?